# Rapid Java Shape Manipulation

Tags: java, model-view-controller, drawing

My team is short on time in implementing a simple shape editor. We have to be able to create, delete, move, and copy simple shapes like rectangles and lines. This has to be a stand-alone application (may not use applets). We've fully implemented our model underpinning the application, as well as the controllers. Any advice?

Edit: This is part of a much larger application. Just missing the presentation element, to clarify.

Comment: It sounds like you've got everything figured out. Can you be more specific about what kind of advice you're looking for?

Comment: Hm. We're trying to get a way to actually *show* the shows on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting to display graphics, check out the Java2D library.

Here is the API: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/2d/spec.html
There are also many many tutorials: (here is one) http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

Just try Googling Java 2D examples or some similar query.

I think you'll find it's actually pretty easy to draw 2D shape in Java :)

Answer (score 1):

I had been using [JHotDraw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jhotdraw/), a figure editor in my own application. You may refer to their source code. They are using design pattern quite extensively.

It is a not too bad figure editor, and it is originated by Erich Gamma, one of the author of classic design pattern.

> JHotDraw is a two-dimensional graphics
>   framework for structured drawing
>   editors that is written in Java. It is
>   based on Erich Gamma's JHotDraw, which
>   is copyright 1996, 1997 by IFA
>   Informatik and Erich Gamma.